# error compiling Android on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am getting following error while compiling Android on ubuntu 11.10

```
target arm C: libc <= bionic/libc/bionic/pthread.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libc_intermediates/bionic/pthread.o] Error 1
```

Any Clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't find cc1. On my fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 it's installed but not in my path. Try adding it manually to your path.

```
export PATH=<pathtoitgoeshere>:$PATH
```

On my Ubuntu, it was found at

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/cc1
```

But you can find it for yours by using

```
gcc -print-prog-name=cc1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the actual problem was cc1 had no execute permission, do you have a list of files that need execute permission?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have such a list myself. I'll leave my answer so people can see yours.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent about a day to find root cause of this: `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file...` and others issues. The issue was that I unpacked NDK and SDK with 7z which removed executable permission for all binaries and Eclipse was not able to start cc1. Once I unpacked tar files of SDK and NDK using tar, everything started working well.

PS. I hope it will safe a day for others.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 => 14.04.

Seems like the build-essential package wasn't upgraded properly. For me, I was able to fix by doing

```
sudo apt-get purge gcc
sudo apt-get install gcc
```